# routing to nested rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to create an rspec to route to a nested resource but I keep getting a `No route matches` error.

```
1) V1::DevicesController scan submitted to #create
     Failure/Error: post "/v1/devices/#{device.serial_number}/scans.json", params: { data: scan }

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"/v1/devices/7929e287466c493ba03947c189cadc81/scans.json", :controller=>"v1/devices", :data=>#<Rack::Test::UploadedFile:0x00556f7c423808 @content_type="application/gzip", @original_filename="sample_test.gz", @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/sample_test.gz20170719-65-sdfczl>>}
```

My spec is pretty simple right now:

**require 'rails_helper'**

```
RSpec.describe V1::DevicesController, type: :controller do
  it "scan submitted to #create" do
    company = Company.create(name: "Test Company", domain: "testcompany.com")
    device = Device.create(name: "Test Device", company_id: company.id)
    scan = fixture_file_upload( "#{Rails.root}/spec/assets/sample_test.gz", 'application/gzip')
    post "/v1/devices/#{device.serial_number}/scans.json", params: { data: scan }
    expect(response).to be_successful
  end    
end
```

**My controller is relatively basic as well:**

```
class V1::ScansController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user_from_token!, only: [:create]
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:create]
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }, only: [:create]

  def create
    @scan = Scan.new(scan_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @scan.save
        # GenerateReport.perform_async(@scan.id)
        format.json { render json: @scan, status: :created }
      else
        format.json { render json: @scan.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

  end


  private

  def set_device
    @device = Device.find_by!(serial_number: params[:device_serial_number])
  end

  def scan_params
    params.require(:scan).permit(:device_serial_number, :data)
  end

end
```

**and my routes file has:**

```
api_version(:module => "V1", :path => {:value => "v1"}) do
  resources :devices, only: [:show, :update], param: :serial_number do
    resources :scans, only: [:create]
  end
end
```

Which yields the following route:

```
v1_device_scans POST   /v1/devices/:device_serial_number/scans(.:format) v1/scans#create
```

So, clearly my route is there... what am I missing?

Comment: the problem comes fron `post "/v1/devices/#{device.serial_number}/scans.json",` you need give it a mapped route symbol.

Comment: what do you mean?  something like `post :create, params: { device_serial_number: device.serial_number }`

Comment: @MathewP.Jones it does seem building the url the way I did the `device.serial_number` does actually get put into the string though.

Comment: yes, usually we put that `action method name` as a symbol there, just try.

Comment: pretty much the same thing: `No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"v1/devices", :data=>#<Rack::Test::UploadedFile:0x0055e05d093380 @content_type="application/gzip", @original_filename="sample_test.gz", @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/sample_test.gz20170719-109-5v46iw>>, :device_serial_number=>"da512d2b15de4bd887161d6cb83e79b2"}`

Comment: Try dropping the `.json` from your request in `post "/v1/devices/#{device.serial_number}/scans.json", params: { data: scan }`; then set the headers to request for `json`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576756/using-rspec-how-do-i-test-the-json-format-of-my-controller-in-rails-3-0-11) may be useful.

Comment: @Gerry dropped `.json` still the same error message.  What do you mean about the headers?

Answer (score 1):

Using a mixture of Mathew and Gerry's ideas I was able to get past the `no route` issue with:

```
post :create, params: { device_serial_number: device.serial_number, scan: { data: scan } }
```

Since my controller has this method, I ended up needing to nest the additional attributes in the `params` hash:

```
  def scan_params
    params.require(:scan).permit(:device_serial_number, :data)
  end
```

Comment: Great! I think we mixed two kinds of params,  we need this `device_serial_number` to route to right action, then we need `data` to give it to action.